# Matlab Plot Graph

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix with 1000 real numbers within range -3 to 3. I have to plot the numbers on a graph so as to get a continuous curve combining all the points. The matrix name is Points and it is 1000 by 1 matrix.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making a plot out of a list of points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857750/making-a-plot-out-of-a-list-of-points)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plot graphs in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884394/plot-graphs-in-matlab)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html) ;)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
plot(Points(:));  % plot the points
ylim([-3 3]);  % set the y limits
```